# Is there a way to set up a default Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I set up loads of custom reports, dashboards, filters, and all sorts on Google Analytics.

When using Google Tag Manager I can just export my container and then import it to all future accounts which is awesome and a real time saver.

Is there anything similar for Google Analytics?

Answer (score 2):

Go into Admin and look for 'Share Assets' under the view you want to copy these things from. There you have a list of all the custom reports, dashboards, goals, segments, channel groupings and remarketing audiences you have in that view. Tick the checkbox for the ones you want to copy, click the share button and you'll get a url to use yourself or send to someone else. Paste that into your browser, you'll get a box to find the property and view you want to copy your assets into.

Comment: So I can share all of the assets in one go? And I can share filters also?